# How to remove an array item from a context menu?

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, listadapter

I have a ListView and would like to remove a row item when the user long clicks on selects Remove from the context menu.

```
@Override  
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Selection Options");  
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Remove Symbol");  
    }  

    @Override  
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
        if(item.getTitle()=="Remove Symbol"){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Remove clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }  
        else {
            return false;
        }  

        return true;  
    }
```

How can I get a reference to the row number that was clicked, so I can remove that index from my array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onContextItemSelected` callback, you can use this code to get the id of the item.

```
@Override
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
     removeItemFromListById(info.id);
  }
```

***Source:***

[Creating Menus | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu)

Comment: how about if i need to remove that item also in the DB?